# Force javamailsender to authenticate

Tags: java, ldap, jakarta-mail

I'm writing an web app, every user can autheticate via ldap, every user has email with same login and password, in java i woudl like send an email with special account, but when i try to authenticate any user authentication fails, but when i'm not giving any username or password to `JavaMailSenderImpl` app sends email with my own email account, how can i force authentication of another user?

```
 @Bean
public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "host");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "NTLM");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth.ntlm.domain", "domain");
    //props.put("mail.smtp.user", "does not metter");

    //sender.setHost("host");
    //sender.setPort(25);
    sender.setJavaMailProperties(props);
    //sender.setUsername("does not metter");
    //sender.setPassword("^does not metter also");
    return sender;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "mail.smtp.auth" to "true", not "false".  And of course set the username and password.

Comment: I had it like that before, but authentication fails credentials for sure were good, but i will try it once again.

Comment: Post the JavaMail debug output if it still fails.

Comment: I found the reason, i was not using te smtps, after seting port to 587 and changeing all props to mail.smtps.* it works fine!